# Create SVG circle with 6 segments

Tags: svg

What would be the most efficient/concise way to create a SVG file with 6 segments?

I'd like to create the SVG **by hand** and *not* pre-calculate the points with some kind of software - if possible.

I think using a path like this would be a start

```
<path d="M 200,200 l 150,0 a150,150 0 0,0 -37,-97 z" 
fill="red" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-linejoin="round" />
```

But can we calculate the points within the SVG somehow?

Any ideas much appreciated!

Comment: I would draw it in a vector programme first such as Illustrator or Inkscape, and then open the SVG in a text editor and see how it works. SVG by hand is notoriously fiddly. By seeing what is generated, you might have a fighting chance :)

Comment: It's like two different questions. Most effective way to create SVG with 6 segments (I take it as 6-part polygon) is to draw it in vector graphics editor. Can we calculate points in SVG? Of course! SVG file uses its own Cartesian coordinate system to precisely and unambiguously define location and size of design elements—points among them. If you want to work by hand then SVG specification is your “best buddy” :}

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand what are you trying to create, but if geometric patterns with numerous repeated details, then one can apply affine transformations to pieces of the graphics already drawn and reuse its code. Here's a geometric example from [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Centered_pentagonal_%3D_1_%2B_5triangular.svg):

[image: Centered pentagonal = 1 + 5triangular]

It is not exactly “calculate all the points within the SVG”, but passing to the SVG engine such tedious tasks as expanding a rotational or reflectional symmetry.